# Adding another data source to existing rpt file Crystal Report

Tags: database, crystal-reports, report

Dears,

Can you please help me if there is a way to add another data source to existing report (rpt file) that I have on production environment, but I only have rpt file not the whole solution.

I tried to add new connection and add the fields I want, but multiple datasources warning appear and rpt file will show blank in browser once I opened it. I tried also to add subreport which depend on the new data source and I linked it with the main report but still same issue blank report in production environment.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

**Update:**

- This is the existing fields in the original rpt file:

[Existing Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMvWs.jpg)

- Database Fields > Database Experts, adding new connection:

[I added new connection, you can see it down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj1c9.jpg)

- After adding, VS will ask me for the old XML File which I don't have it so I will just click cancel then the new fields will be added to Database Fields. At this point, rpt file will be shown as blank. Any help with this issue?

[VS Asking for old XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URi3u.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to replace the data source (old XML file) with a new data source (new XML file). In that case, use the menu option of:
***Database, Set Datasource Location...***

Answer (score 0):

Linking to a second data source in the main report requires that the link is based only on one column and that this shared column has the same data type and size.

If you need a more complex join, then going with a subreport is a good option.
Start by creating a new main report that acts as the design of the subreport. If it returns the expected information, insert it as a subreport. That step cannot cause the the main report to go blank. You should then be able to add a link to the subreport and make progress.